# Visual Basic fetching data from mysql table

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to fetch some data from table and get error:"Invalid object name 'h'".My code is

```vb
 Dim h As Decimal
'some code
 cmd2 = New SqlCommand("insert into h select KvotaX from dbo.Utakmice where ID=@s1 ", conn)


 cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s1", myReader.GetInt32(1))
'some code
 f = cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. KvotaX from dbo.Utakmice data type is real.

Comment: Does table h exists for sure?

Comment: That's a good sign. It means you successfully connected to the database and submitted your query, and were able to handle a response from the database server. A lot of things have already gone right. Now, do you have a table in your database named "h"?

Comment: Actualy h is decimal variable.I'm trying to fetch data into variable. Declaration is first line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to set the value of h using a sql statement. This is not correct.

```
Dim h As Decimal
cmd2 = New SqlCommand("select KvotaX from dbo.Utakmice where ID=@s1 ", conn)
cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s1", myReader.GetInt32(1))
h = Convert.ToDecimal(cmd2.ExecuteScalar)
```

You `select` the record corresponding to the parameter passed in and then read the return value of the ExecuteScalar method. Note that this works only if the query returns one record and only one column. Better to be safe checking the return value before assigning to the decimal

```
Dim o = cmd2.ExecuteScalar
if o IsNot Nothing Then
    h = Convert.ToDecimal(o)
    .....
End If
```

However, your code hints to the fact that you are trying to get the value for the s1 parameters reading from an open MySqlDataReader. This could not be possible because, usually, the connection used by the datareader is busy till the datareader remains open.

Comment: It works fine. I don't have problem with MySqlDataReader connection.Maybe it's because I have MultipleActiveResultSets=true; within connection string.

Comment: Good to know, I was just searching if that key was valid also for MySql.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want the **`insert into h`** if you are just trying to **fetch data**.

**Remove** that phrase and see if you get what you are expecting.